# Armazenamento de Cookies e Requisições com Cookies

Tags: http, navegador-de-internet, http-request, cookies, cross-browser

Os cookies da página são enviados para o servidor em todas as requisições ou somente quando ele é intencionalmente enviado através do javascript?

O localStorage é armazenado na cache do browser, e o cookie? Ele é armazenado no browser ou em algum outro lugar do pc do usuário?

O cookie é crossbrowser? (Eu havia confundido o conceito de cross-browser, antes achava que estava relacionado a algo "compartilhado" entre os browser, e não a definição real de algo "compatível" entre os browsers).

Desde já agradeço as respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Um cookie HTTP (um cookie web ou cookie de browser) normalmente é utilizado para identificar se duas requisições vieram do mesmo navegador — ao manter um usuário logado, por exemplo. Ele guarda informações dinâmicas para o protocolo HTTP sem estado.
Ou seja sim sempre envia(caso criado) e o servidor tem acesso.

2-Ao contrário dos cookies, o limite de armazenamento é muito maior (pelo menos 5 MB) e as informações nunca são transferidas para o servidor.

O armazenamento na Web é por origem (por domínio e protocolo). Todas as páginas, de uma origem, podem armazenar e acessar os mesmos dados.
O armazenamento é feito individualmente em cada browser.

3- Tanto localStorage e coockies são cross-browser, segue um exemplo de compatibilidade no localStorage:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E cookies:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No contexto das JWTs , o Stormpath escreveu um artigo bastante útil, descrevendo possíveis maneiras de armazená-las e as (des) vantagens relacionadas a cada método segue o link: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/